# How to find the corresponding matrix of a dot product over a polynomial ring to a specific basis

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, matrices, inner-products, orthogonality

Let $V= \mathbb R[x]_{\leq 2}$ be the vector-space of real polynomials with degree $\leq 2$. We define a dot product on the $V$ as follows:
$$\left<f,g \right> = \int_{0}^1f(x)g(x)dx.$$

Question: What is the corresponding matrix $A := ( \left< b_i,b_j \right> )_{i,j}$ with respect to the basis $B=\{1,x,x²\}$ of $V$?

My approach until now looks like this:
$\int_0^1 (ax²+bx+c)(dx²+ex+f) dx$

Comment: I've tried to edit the question. See if it's fine.

Comment: Thank you! Seems right. I haven't got much experience with Latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seek a $3\times 3$ matrix
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The formula for $a_{ij}$ is
$$
a_{ij}=\int_0^1 e_i(x)\cdot e_j(x)\,dx
$$
where
\begin{align*}
e_1(x) &= 1 & e_2(x) &= x & e_3(x) &= x^2
\end{align*}
For example,
$$
a_{11} = \int_0^1 e_1(x)\cdot e_1(x)\,dx=\int_0^11\cdot1\,dx=\int_0^1\,dx=1
$$
Can you compute the other eight entries?

Answer (score 1):

All we have to do is evaluate the $9$ integrals ($5$ really). You don't have to try and find the general form of the inner product to compute $A$. The basis elements are all from the set $\{1,x,x^2\}$, so the integrals you need to evaluate are

$$\left[\begin{matrix}\langle 1,1\rangle=\int\limits_0^11\,dx&\langle 1,x\rangle=\int\limits_0^1x\,dx&\langle 1,x^2\rangle=\int\limits_0^1x^2\,dx
\\\langle x,1\rangle=\int\limits_0^1x\,dx&\langle x,x\rangle=\int\limits_0^1x^2\,dx&\langle x,x^2\rangle=\int\limits_0^1x^3\,dx
\\\langle x^2,1\rangle=\int\limits_0^1x^2\,dx&\langle x^2,x\rangle=\int\limits_0^1x^3\,dx&\langle x^2,x^2\rangle=\int\limits_0^1x^4\,dx\end{matrix}\right]$$